# clojure throws error by macro list result evaluation

Tags: macros, clojure

I have written such a simple clojure program:

```
(defmacro lister[n]
  (let
    [x (range n)]
    `(max ~@(x))
  )
)

; (macroexpand (lister 5))
(lister 5)
```

When I try evaluate (lister 5) clojure exits with error:

CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to 
clojure.lang.IFn, compiling:(:30:3)

What I am doing wrongly? When I subsitute x with its value - (range 10) macros works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the parens around x.

```
(defmacro lister[n]
  (let [x (range n)]
    `(max ~@x)))
```

You could actually write this more simply with this too:

```
(defmacro lister[n]
  `(max ~@(range n)))
```

Comment: Expanding on your answer, `(x)` means `x` will be evaluated as a function, hence the error `clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFnp`. Remember that first element of a list is always evaluated as a function ;)